# how to get mobile messages using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I have to get messages from mobile so I am using [this plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/sms). It is working but I get no messages, just printing the result `Instance of 'SmsMessage'` in the console, but I did everything specified in document example. did I make any mistakes?

source code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:sms/sms.dart';

class MessagesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  MessagesScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MessagesScreenState createState() => _MessagesScreenState();
}

class _MessagesScreenState extends State<MessagesScreen> {
  List _allMessages;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getAllMessages();
  }

  Future getAllMessages() async {
    SmsQuery query = new SmsQuery();
    List<SmsMessage> messages = await query.getAllSms;
    debugPrint("Total Messages : " + messages.length.toString());
    print(messages);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Messages"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 1,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Text("Test");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: console screenshot]

Comment: Did you request read SMS permission?

Comment: Are you planning only Android support. On iOS you cant do this. Be sure before proceeding further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you describe is actually normal. The messages will be returned as an instance of the SmsMessage class.

When you try to print an object, it is converted to a string. By default the toString method will display `Instance of "Class name"`; and in your case, that's why you are having that output, you are trying to print a list of objects.

If for each of the messages, you would like to display the body, this code snippet should help you:

```dart
Future getAllMessages() async {
    SmsQuery query = new SmsQuery();
    List<SmsMessage> messages = await query.getAllSms;
    debugPrint("Total Messages : " + messages.length.toString());
    messages.forEach((element) { print(element.body); });
}
```

Comment: thanks bro , it works well enough. actually i was tried messages.body without looping,  i thought it would print all messages inside of those list. thank u so much

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with SMS messages, you just cannot print a list of custom objects that way.

Go through the list in a loop and print the property of every message that you want to print. Just like you would have to do with any other complex object.

Comment: actually i printed it because to know available properties of list of messages. unfortunately i wasn't get. anyway thanks.

Comment: Well, normally you look that up in the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/sms/latest/sms/SmsMessage-class.html).